# Ticking noise during acceleration

Tags: noise, acceleration, tahoe

I have a 98 Tahoe with 150,000 miles. When I accelerate from a dead stop I hear a ticking noise from under the vehicle. It is not present when idling or deccelerating. If I accelerate slowly the ticking is not present. Only when I give it a little more gas. Any insight would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to narrow it down to suspension or engine noise?

Comment: Could be an exhaust manifold leak.

Comment: Could be a worn u-joint on the driveshaft. Do you also hear it when going up hills?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-ignition , maybe. What octane gasoline is it supposed to take, and what are you putting in it? Pre-ignition generally ticks when you put the engine under load, especially going up a hill, or "putting your foot" in the gas pedal. If the car is supposed to be run with 91 or 93 octane fuel, and you're using 87 that could cause pre-ignition and a ticking noise.